# Why is numpy.ravel() required in this code that produces small multiples?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I found some code to generate a set of [small multiples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_multiple) and it is working perfectly.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6,3, figsize=(21,21))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.3, wspace=.175)
for ax, data in zip(axes.ravel(), clean_sets):
    ax.plot(data.ETo, "o")
```

The line `for ax, data in zip(axes.ravel(), clean_sets):` contians `.ravel()` but I do not understand what this is actually doing or why it is necessary.

**If I take a look at the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) I find the following:**

> Return a contiguous flattened array.
>
> A 1-D array, containing the elements of the input, is returned. A copy is made only if needed.

I guess the return that corresponds to axes from `plt.subplot()` is a multidimensional array that can't be iterated over, but really I'm not sure. A simple explanation would be greatly appreciated.

**What is the purpose of using `.ravel()` in this case?**

Comment: You are creating 6 rows and 3 columns of `axes` to plot in your figure. I believe `clean_sets` has the data that you want to plot on each axes. I believe `len(clean_sets)` is 18. Now you want to plot all 18 sets on each axes. But axes.shape is `(6,3)`. Meaning if you want to access 10th `axes` to plot 10th `clean_set`, you would have to access axes[1][3], but with `axes.ravel()`, it's `axes.ravel()[9]`. The binding now is linear. In other words, from n*n matrix of axes now, you have 1-d array of axes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your guess is correct. `plt.subplots()` returns either an `Axes` or a `numpy` array of several axes, depending on the input. In case a 2D grid is defined by the arguments `nrows` and `ncols`, the returned `numpy` array will be a 2D array as well.

This behaviour is explained in the [`pyplot.subplots` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) inside the `squeeze` argument,

> `squeeze` : bool, optional, default: True
> If True, extra dimensions are squeezed out from the returned Axes object:

> - if only one subplot is constructed (nrows=ncols=1), the resulting single Axes object is returned as a scalar.

- for Nx1 or 1xN subplots, the returned object is a 1D numpy object array of Axes objects are returned as numpy 1D arrays.
- for NxM, subplots with N>1 and M>1 are returned as a 2D arrays.

> If False, no squeezing at all is done: the returned Axes object is always a 2D array containing Axes instances, even if it ends up being 1x1.

Since here you have `plt.subplots(6,3)` and hence `N>1, M>1`, the resulting object is necessarily a 2D array, independent of what `squeeze` is set to.

This makes it necessary to flatten this array in order to be able to `zip` it. Options are

- `zip(axes.ravel())`
- `zip(axes.flatten())`
- `zip(axes.flat)`